# Java: TCP connection in the background thread. How to display JDialog?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, tcp

I am trying to send a message to server via TCP/IP, wait for the response, and perform further actions dependent on the response. While the communication is in the background process, a Dialog with spinning activity indicator should be displayed. Furthermore, if there is an error in the connection, another JDialog should be displayed.

This is the method that invokes the connection as a result of pressing a button:

```
public void sendMessage()
{
   JFrame f = new JFrame(); 
   JDialog modalDialog = new JDialog(f, "Busy", Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
   modalDialog.setSize(200, 100);
   modalDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(f);
   modalDialog.setUndecorated(true);
   // Remove menu buttons
   modalDialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
   modalDialog.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.WHITE );
   // Add rotating activity indicator
   ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("src/images/activityIndicator.gif");
   modalDialog.add(new JLabel("Please wait... ", loading, JLabel.CENTER));
   // Set activity indicator visible
   modalDialog.setVisible(true);

    // Create connection object
    IGAConnectionTCP t = new IGAConnectionTCP(makeMessageToServerFlightplan());

    // Start connection
    t.start();

    synchronized(t)
    {
        /* Create notification dialog */         
        try
        {
            t.wait();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {

        }


        /*  When the activity in the background thread ends, change GUI on the
            dispatch thread. */
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        { 
            t.closeConnection();

            // Close the pop-up menu when finished
            modalDialog.setVisible(false);
            modalDialog.dispose();

        }); 
    }
}
```

This is the TCP Connection class:

```
public class IGAConnectionTCP extends Thread
{
  /** Object to AppSingleton */
  AppSingleton appSingleton = AppSingleton.getInstance( );
  /** Terminator: Message from the server that ends the connection. */
  private final String  terminator = "END_IGOCONNECT_DATA";
  /** Message that will be sent to the server. */
  private String messageToServer;
  /** Instance of Socket. */
  Socket socket;
  /** Instance of DataInputStream. */    
  DataInputStream input;
  /** Instance of DataOutputStream. */  
  DataOutputStream output;
  /** Instance of BufferedReader. */  
  BufferedReader br;
  /** Message that will be sent from the server. */
  private String messageFromServer;

  public IGAConnectionTCP(String messageToServer)
  {
    this.messageToServer = messageToServer;
  }


  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    synchronized(this)
    {
        setMessageFromServer(connectClient());
        notify();

        System.out.println("FULL DATA:");
        System.out.println(getMessageFromServer());
    }
  }

  /**
   * http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/139154-transfer-a-file-over-tcp/
   * @return Message received from the Server
   */
  public String connectClient()
  {
    String data = "";

    try
    {
        // Get IP Address and Port
        int serverPort = appSingleton.getIpPortShared();
        String ip = appSingleton.getIpAddressShared();

        // Create socket, input and output
        socket = new Socket(ip, serverPort);
        input = new DataInputStream( socket.getInputStream());
        output = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream());

        //Send message to the Server
        output.writeBytes(messageToServer);

        // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        //Read Response
        // ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s = "";

        int value = 0;

        while((value = br.read()) != -1) 
        {
            // converts int to character
            char c = (char)value;

            sb.append(c);

            if(sb.toString().contains(terminator))
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Return data obtained from the Server
        data = sb.toString();
    }

    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        String message = "Application was not able to establish connection.\n"
                + "Check whether IP Address and Port number were correctly entered \n"
                + "in Settings. Check whether connection is not being blocked by \n"
                + "your firewall.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "TCP Connection Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    catch (EOFException e)
    {
        String message = "Application was not able to establish connection.\n"
                + "Check whether IP Address and Port number were correctly entered \n"
                + "in Settings. Check whether connection is not being blocked by \n"
                + "your firewall.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "TCP Connection Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        String message = "Application was not able to establish connection.\n"
                + "Check whether IP Address and Port number were correctly entered \n"
                + "in Settings. Check whether connection is not being blocked by \n"
                + "your firewall.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message, "TCP Connection Error",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    finally 
    {
       // Needed??
    }

    return data;
  } 


  public void closeConnection()
  {
    try
    {
        System.out.println("CHECK WETHER CLOSING IS DONE HERE");

        if(socket!=null)
        {
            socket.close();
        }
        if(input != null)
        {
            input.close();
        }
        if(output != null)
        {
            output.close();
        }
        if(br != null)
        {
            br.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(IGAConnectionTCP.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    socket = null;
    input = null;
    output = null;
    br = null;
  }

  /**
   * Gets message to be sent from the Server.
   * @return Message to be sent from the Server.
   */
  public String getMessageFromServer() {
    return messageFromServer;
  }

  /**
   * Sets message to be sent from the Server.
   * @param messageFromServer Message to be sent from the Server.
   */
  public void setMessageFromServer(String messageFromServer) {
    this.messageFromServer = messageFromServer;
  }
}
```

My problem is that the JDialog does not show the activity indicator and the "Please wait..." sign. And when the error occurs, the JDiagog is blank as well. I do know this is happening because of the threading problem. What would be the best way to address it?

Thank you!

Comment: You're calling `t.wait();` on the Swing event thread, stomping that thread. What do you expect your application to do in this situation?

Comment: Plus you have a bunch of code **after** setting a modal dialog visible. That code won't be called until the dialog is no longer visible.

Comment: Other issues -- why are you extending Thread? While this is not causing your error, almost any threading tutorial will universally recommend against doing this and will usually list their good reasons for this recommendation. Also for better help, try to condense your problem and your code into a small [mcve], code that we can compile, run and test for ourselves.

Comment: Also... you're displaying JOptionPanes **off** of the Swing event thread, not good. Those need to be queued onto the EDT just like any other Swing call made from a background thread (excepting calls to `repaint()`).

Comment: Thanks. 1) The code after setting the modal dialog is called. 2) I have made a simple code with similar code and the problem with error messages is not replicated. But it does exist in the application. 3) The modal dialog is called in the EDT but the problem still exists. Any hint how to queue the Error Dialog to the EDT in this situation? Thank you!

Comment: The error joptionpanes are queued onto the EDT same as any other bit of code. By placing it into a Runnable and passing that into a queuing method via SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Comment: Ah, I now see that you've misnamed your JDialog variable. You call it `modalDialog`, but construct it as a modeless dialog (`ModalityType.MODELESS`), which is ***very*** confusing. Please don't do that to us or to your future self.

Comment: Consider a delegate model.  Pass a reference of an observer to your background process, which will call defined methods when some action occurs, which an interested party (the observer/delegate) can then take action upon. As has previously been mentioned, make sure that any modifications to the UI state are done in the context of the EDT

Comment: Yep, what HE ^^^^^ said.

Comment: Unlike Swift where the delegate model is so easy, Java's delegates are somewhat hard to understand for me. But I will try. Thank you!

Comment: You would need to roll your own. I usually use SwingPropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeListeners for my delegates.

Comment: I still do not understand why the modelDialog JDialog is a blank panel. It is called on the main thread...